# Google Places API reference - length/characteristics

Tags: google-places-api

After searching both Google Documentation and the web, I cannot find what definite characteristics a Places 'reference' has. Mainly the (max) length of a reference so it can be stored in a database.

It seems that trialling these IDs they are always 211 characters (max) of alphanumeric characters including dashes and underscores.

However, as I say I cannot find any official docs on this and I don't want to assume that as I already have encountered an issue where the reference loaded from the database does not work with the Places Details API from Google. (Even though the retrieved reference follows the same characteristics as above).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

There is no documentation for this as we can not guarantee the max length because each reference contains information specified by the user relating the corresponding search request.

If you are using a SQL database, I would suggest using a varchar with a high maximum number.

Answer (score 0):

Although most of the API reference ids are 211 chars long, there are some ref ids which are 234 chars long also.

Use a substring of the ref id if you have memory constraints.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are apparently some with 255 too.

Answer (score 0):

I see one reference that have 276 length